# Difference of -e, -u and -o pipefail in bash exit status

Tags: bash

Being trying to properly guard for non-zero exits on a bash script.

What is the difference between -e, -u and -o pipefail?

-o pipefail is not sufficient to exit with an error code?

Comment: Have you read this?
http://redsymbol.net/articles/unofficial-bash-strict-mode/

Comment: This one is useful, thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`set -e`: Exit immediately if a command exits with a non-zero status.

`set -u`: If you try to access an undefined variable, that is an error.

`set -o pipefail`: If any command in a pipeline returns a non-zero exit code, the return code of the entire pipeline is the exit code of the last failed command.