# Is git ls-remote able to use GITHUB variables? Error: Process completed with exit code 2

Tags: github-actions, git-ls-remote

Actions code:

```yaml
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout codes
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Test git for actions
        shell: bash
        run: |
          ## use GitHub variables, such as: GITHUB_REF,GITHUB_HEAD_REF..
          BRANCH=${GITHUB_REF##*/}
          branch=$BRANCH
          git ls-remote --heads --exit-code repo_url "$branch" >/dev/null
          if [ "$?" == "1" ]
          then 
            echo "Branch doesn't exist"
          else
            echo "Branch exist"
          fi
```

It will occur the following error:

```bash
  BRANCH=${GITHUB_REF##*/}
  branch=${BRANCH}
  echo $branch
  git ls-remote --heads --exit-code repo_url "$branch" >/dev/null
  if [ "$?" == "1" ]
  then 
    echo "Branch doesn't exist"
  else
    echo "Branch exist"
  fi

  shell: /usr/bin/bash --noprofile --norc -e -o pipefail {0}
main
Error: Process completed with exit code 2.
```

When I replace `${GITHUB_REF}` with `main`, it works fine.

```bash
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Test git for actions
        shell: bash
        run: |
          ## use GitHub variables, such as: GITHUB_REF,GITHUB_HEAD_REF..
          BRANCH=${GITHUB_REF##*/}
          branch=main
          git ls-remote --heads --exit-code repo_url "$branch" >/dev/null
          if [ "$?" == "1" ]
          then 
            echo "Branch doesn't exist"
          else
            echo "Branch exist"
          fi
```

Output:

```bash
  BRANCH=${GITHUB_REF##*/}
  branch=main
  echo $branch
  git ls-remote --heads --exit-code repo_url "$branch" >/dev/null
  if [ "$?" == "1" ]
  then 
    echo "Branch doesn't exist"
  else
    echo "Branch exist"
  fi
main
Branch exist
```

Is the `git ls-remote` command not able to use variables?

I want to check whether a certain branch exists in the remote warehouse in GitHub Actions.

Comment: Directly check the command in `if` i.e. `if git ls-remote ...; then`. `bash` in GHA runs with `-e` and `-o pipefail` flags which makes it exit on failure. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/69582574/7670262 for more details.

Comment: In my case `ls-remote` returns `2` if the branch doesn't exist, `0` otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [`jobs.<job_id>.steps[*].shell`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idstepsshell), the default Bash invocation is:

```bash
bash --noprofile --norc -eo pipefail {0}
```

which makes it to [fail fast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fail-fast) as described under [Exit codes and error action preference](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#exit-codes-and-error-action-preference), for `bash`:

> Fail-fast behavior using `set -eo pipefail`: This option is set when `shell: bash` is explicitly specified.

And, according to [Bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html), under [The Set Builtin](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#The-Set-Builtin):

> `-e`: Exit immediately if a pipeline (see Pipelines), which may consist of a single simple command (see Simple Commands), a list (see Lists of Commands), or a compound command (see Compound Commands) returns a non-zero status. The shell does not exit if the command that fails is part of the command list immediately following a `while` or `until` keyword, part of the test in an `if` statement, part of any command executed in a `&&` or `||` list except the command following the final `&&` or `||`, any command in a pipeline but the last, or if the command’s return status is being inverted with `!`. If a compound command other than a subshell returns a non-zero status because a command failed while `-e` was being ignored, the shell does not exit. A trap on `ERR`, if set, is executed before the shell exits.

and,

> `-o pipefail`: If set, the return value of a pipeline is the value of the last (rightmost) command to exit with a non-zero status, or zero if all commands in the pipeline exit successfully. This option is disabled by default.

---

In your case, the possible solution could be to directly handle the exit status of the command in an `if`:

```bash
if command; then
  # succes
else
  # failure
end
```

i.e.

```bash
if ! git ls-remote --heads --exit-code repo_url "$branch" >/dev/null
then 
  echo "Branch doesn't exist"
else
  echo "Branch exist"
fi
```

or,

```bash
if git ls-remote --heads --exit-code repo_url "$branch" >/dev/null
then 
  echo "Branch exist"
else
  echo "Branch doesn't exist"
fi
```